# Problem using elem.dataset with IE and JSFiddle

Tags: javascript

In this JSFiddle I created on Chrome, I find that it's unable to work on IE (I'm using IE9). Any reason as to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSB67/.

```
var backImage = [
    "http://alm7.wikispaces.com/file/view/RedBackground.bmp/144018347/RedBackground.bmp",
    "http://www.time2man-up.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/black-background.jpg",
    "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--GorNQoEUxg/TfWPyckVeMI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0208KqQf3ds/s1600/yellow_background.jpg",
    ""
    ];

function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body) {
        document.body.style.background = "url(\"" + backImage[whichImage] + "\")";
    }
}
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bg_swap'),
    button;

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = function() {
        changeBGImage(this.dataset.index);
    };
}
```

Comment: I have four hyperlinks with a class of .bg_swap and a index (data-index) of numbers in ascending order. When I click on them, they are supposed to set the background of the page corresponding to the index of the element to the index of the array (backImage). I'm Chrome and checked on IE9 and it doesn't work.

Comment: `this.dataset` is showing up as undefined in IE9, so your onclick handler never even calls the changeBGImage()

Answer (score 111, accepted):

IE < 10 does not support `elem.dataset`. You'd need to explicitly get the attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSB67/1/.

```
changeBGImage(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
```

In the future, you might want pressing F12 and looking at the console for errors, since it said what was causing the problem here.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks for your answer. +1 for you.

Comment: For more detail about usage and support the mozilla developer docs are good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 9):

`this.dataset.index` does not work on IE.  Try using `this.getAttribute("data-index")`.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why the `dataset` property is not recognized by older versions of IE (actually all of them except IE11+) is the fact that it was introduced in HTML5 which those versions do not support or support it only partially.

In order to obtain this property's value, one can use pure js like

```
changeBGImage(this.attributes.getNamedItem("data-index").value)
```

or simplier by using the getAttribute() method:

```
changeBGImage(this.getAttribute("data-index"))
```

or jQuery (v 1.2.3+):

```
$(".bg_swap").click(function(){
    changeBGImage($(this).data("index"));
})
```

Comment: Correct. I don't really understand why people have the need to support outdated browsers anyway. Usage of IE10 and below is max. 6.3% of all browsers and this low usage percentage includes Edge and IE11, so there are max. (!) 1.4% of old IE browsers out there. Writing such backward compatible code is waste of time and money - especially since all major browsers are free with automatic free updates. Finally, jQuery fixes it anyway. See: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: It's in cases when your customer is not able / allowed to install a modern browser. For example a state institution with outdated computers.

Comment: @StanE question created in 2011 ~ at that time support might be needed. ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, you're absolutely right. I miss the date sometimes, sorry. :-)

Answer (score 5):

`dataset` seems to be undefined in IE. That is probably the major source of the issue. Everything else works just fine on IE9 64 bit.

You could just store that state locally in JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    register( i )

function register( i ){
    button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = function() {
        changeBGImage(i);
    };
}
```

Or you can do a lookup

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = function() {
        changeBGImage(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a `data()` method which also works in the IE Version I have tested (IE8 and IE10).

Check the documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/data/