# Problems with js property value in IE9

Tags: javascript, youtube, internet-explorer-9

I have this code:

```
// async youtube frames
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement('div');

        if (typeof v[n].dataset.id == 'undefined' || v[n].dataset.id == null) {
            return;
        }
        p.innerHTML = createYoutubeImage(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = createYoutubeFrame;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
```

For async youtube frames. When I'm trying to open my page in IE9 (yes I know that's old) my console showing me sth like this:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined
```

and the error appear in line where if starts. What should be done here to fix that ?

Comment: your html tag attribute should set `data-id="xxx"`???

Comment: I guess `dataset` is coming as `undefined`. Try this: `if(v[n].dataset && !v[n].dataset.id) return`.

Comment: According to [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), *data-* attribute and *dataset* are only supported in IE 11+. That should be confirmed by other sources (e.g. [*Problem using elem.dataset with IE and JSFiddle*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127896/problem-using-elem-dataset-with-ie-and-jsfiddle)). Use *getAttribute* instead.