# How to assign value to dataset variable in IE10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm developing a little script using vanilla Javascript and I'm trying to assign a value to a dataset variable like this:

```
(function(e,l,b,u,t,n){
    t=l.createElement(b);
    t.dataset.id='my-script';
    t.dataset.orgId='34';
})(window,document,'script','https://example.com/assets/my_script.js');
```

However, when testing this in IE10 and 9 I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference

After some research, I learned that `elem.dataset` is not supported by internet explorer 10. But I haven't been able to find a way to assign a value to that element, I tried something like this:

```
(function(e,l,b,u,t,n){
    t=l.createElement(b);

    if (t.dataset)
        t.dataset.id='my-script';
    else
        t.setAttribute('id', 'my-script');
    t.async=1;

    t.src=u;

    if (t.dataset)
        t.dataset.orgId='34';
    else
        t.setAttribute('orgId', '34');
})(window,document,'script','https://exampl.com/assets/my_script.js');
```

But to no avail.

Comment: What's the problem with the second one?

Comment: Do you mean `data-org-id`?

Comment: What's the point of assigning a value to the dataset when dataset isn't supported? (And do your really want to support IE10 which doesn't get security updates, has an estimated market share of 0.06%, and requires a whole lot of extra work?)

Comment: Qentin I need to assign those values to be able to find a script stored in a external API. I found this question in which they are able to find the value using: something a long the lines of 
this.getAttribute('data-index')
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127896/problem-using-elem-dataset-with-ie-and-jsfiddle

Comment: Basically I want to find a functional replacement for t.dataset.orgId='34'; in a way that works for IE10

Comment: `t.setAttribute("data-org-id", "34")`

Comment: See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills and search for `dataset` to find various polyfills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataset` attributes always begin with `data-`. You need to use that prefix in your code.

And the attribute should be un-camelcased, so `orgId` becomes `data-org-id`.

```
(function(e,l,b,u,t,n){
    t=l.createElement(b);

    if (t.dataset)
        t.dataset.id='my-script';
    else
        t.setAttribute('data-id', 'my-script');
    t.async=1;

    t.src=u;

    if (t.dataset)
        t.dataset.orgId='34';
    else
        t.setAttribute('data-org-id', '34');
})(window,document,'script','https://exampl.com/assets/my_script.js');
```